# how we can give a div scroll for touch and for windows?

Tags: css, scroll, sidebar, menubar

**I try several ways but not working**

This code is for sidebar menu but scroll not working !!!

```
div .sidebar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 20px;
    transition: left 0.6s;
    z-index: 2;
    height: 920px;
    max-height: 920px;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

If anyone know way answer